# Unable to clip raster to desired shape

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, clip

I am trying to clip a raster to the shape of a polygon as shown in image 1[image].

But the result that I get is as shown in image 2[image].

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using?

Comment: Also, are you doing anything with the Environment Settings before you run the Clip tool? You can change the raster cell size under 'Raster Analysis.'

Comment: no, not doing anything to the Environment. I had tried setting cell size to 1.5 in one trial, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: What is the cell size of the input raster?

Comment: BTW I am using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Comment: Cell size is 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the Clip tool, make sure to check the box that says "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry"

You can also set a clipping extent in the layer properties by right clicking "Layers" in the table of contents pane, select the Data Frame tab, and under clip options expand the drop down menu, select "clip to shape" and select the feature you with to clip by.  this method will clip every layer in the table of contents to the specified shape.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I did as you suggested. It is still clipping the layer in the shape of a rectangle, not in the shape of the irregular polygon.

Comment: You tried both methods? Make sure that the "Maintain Clipping Extent" box is also checked when you run Clip (Data management Tools > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip)

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't seem to make a difference. :-(

Comment: If you could provide more specifics regarding your workflow, it will be easier to nail down the problem.

Comment: I have a shp in the shape of Illinois. I have rain data for a few stations. I used idw to get the purple image that I have shared in my question. I want that idw file to be clipped in the shape of illinois. So I used clip like you suggested, but it is still in the shape of a rectangle, and worse, the image is changing to the black/grey/white rectangles.

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward workflow.  The only thing I can think of, as @juturna suggested, is that there could be something in your environment settings that is causing this output.  Try running IDW again and processing  the new result, perhaps something is wrong with the output you're trying to clip.

Comment: Those "black/grey/white rectangles" are cells of your output raster, so after you have figured out how to reduce your cell size in the environment settings or another part of your workflow, you can change the color ramp under the layer's Properties/Symbology so that it isn't just in grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clip is being performed correctly, but the raster size of the output is too big. Also the symbology of the output is set to a simple black/white colour ramp. Here are the solutions ...

**Raster size**

You are using the Clip (Data Management) tool and as Jeff said you need to check the box "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry". Then you can adjust the raster size by looking in the environment variables as shown here

[image]

**Symbology**

When you have your new output layer you can right click on it/Properties/Symbology. Then you can import the symbology from your original IDW layer as shown below

[image]

Otherwise you should not need to touch any environment variables so if the problem still remains I wonder if you have changed another environment variable from default settings ?

Comment: Thanks, I had changed the environment like you suggested. But that didn't change much either. While I was able to change the look of it from those boxes to a better symbology, the problem of it being not clipped to the shape of the polygon remains. I will update here if I do manage to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I used Image Analysis tool as suggested in method 2 of this link http://gisgeography.com/clip-rasters-arcgis-polygon-boundary/

Here's the final image
[image]

Comment: I am happy that at least part of my answer was helpful. It is still unclear why the clip tool did not work using the standard interface - the Image Analysis toolbar uses the same tool I believe. Anyway you got there in the end!